# Need to create a policy in azure that ensures data in transit & rest data is encrypted

Tags: azure, azure-policy

We need to create a policy in azure that ensures data in transit(when communicating with a database)  and rest data in database is encrypted. Is it possible to implement it via azure policy? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need an Azure Policy to enforce Encryption at Rest and Encryption in Transit as they are enabled **by default** for all newly databases.

For TDE (rest) please refer to the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transparent-data-encryption-tde-overview?tabs=azure-portal

For encryption in transit, you may refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/security-overview#transport-layer-security-encryption-in-transit

If you want to check if an existing older database has TDE enabled (via portal), select your database, navigate to the Security section and check the transparent data encryption.
[image]

[image]

We also have an option of **Always Encrypted** - for specific highly sensitive columns. You can get more details in the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#feature-details

A similar question in SO can be found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086054/5344880